# bash for loop with file input not working

Tags: bash, file-io, for-loop

I'm making a loop that takes input from a file to determine whether a user is permitted to use a specific program.

```
#!/bin/bash

boole=false

echo "Username: "
read username

echo "debug0"

for((line=1; $boole=false; line++)); do
    echo "debug.5"
    auth=`head -n $line users | tail -n $line`

    echo "debug1"

    if [ $username = $auth ]; then
        echo "debug2"
        echo "authentication success"
        read
        exit 0
    fi

    if [ $auth = "#end" ]; then
        echo "debug3"
        echo "authentication failed"
        read
        exit 0
    fi
done

echo "skip everything"
```

The output is

```
Username:
admin
debug0
skip everything
```

The file with the users has

```
root
admin
...
#end
```

`#end` and `boole` should tell the loop to end

This is just the debugging stage so it doesn't actually execute any program, it's just supposed to tell me whether or not a user is allowed to use it.

Comment: In your for loop, `$boole=false` will expand to `false=false`, Probably not what you want. remove the `$`. Good luck.

Comment: This seems kind of an inefficient way to read a file -- why not just use a `while read ...` loop?

Comment: Or, better, yet, `grep -q "^${username}$" users && .....`?

Comment: change "bash" to "bash -vx"

Comment: @twalberg No, that's not better -- what if the username contains a regex subexpression such as `[foo]`? Then that grep will never match it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Valid point. However, the original question does not seem to contemplate such usage, nor does the code quoted in the question - although switching to `[[ ... ]]` syntax over `[ ... ]` might provide some additional benefit along those lines...

Comment: @twalberg I wasn't talking about _intentional_ regexes, but _unintentional_ ones -- where interpreting as a BRE (which grep does when not given `-F`) would be a bug, not a feature.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah. Well, in that case, `grep -Fq ...`. But, on the other hand, if you have regex characters in your user names, you're likely to be running into other issues as well...

Comment: @twalberg Even a period is a regex character. They're not that uncommon or hard to hit.

Comment: In a C-style for loop, all variables are processed in an arithmetic context. `false=false` is equivalent to `0=0`, which is always true. Therefore, your loop never starts.

Answer (score 0):

Loops in bash are not like C loops. Basic syntax is:

```
for arg in [list]
do 
    [command(s)...]
done
```

There is however a C-style syntax like the one you are using:

```
for ((x=1; x<=3; x++))
{
    echo $x
}
```

As mentioned in a comment, when you write `$boole=false` inside double parentheses, `$boole` is dereferenced *before* the contents of the double parentheses is processed, and thus becomes `false=false`. Furthermore, when you enclose something in double parentheses you should use `==` for comparing. In any case, be that `$boole=false` or `$boole==false`, they will both be true as the first one successfully assigns `false` to `false`, and the second one is true because of a `false==false` being true.

Anyway, in your case I'd probably use a while loop. Here's an example:

```
bool=true
int=1
while $bool; do
    echo $int
    (( int++ ))
    if [[ $int == 10 ]]; then
        bool=false
    fi
done
echo $int
```

Comment: `bash` does have C-style for loops, though.

Comment: If you have bash 4, I'd give Charles' answer a try. Alternatively I'd use Python :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop, not a for loop, when reading files. This is documented in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

```
while read -r line; do
  something_with "$line"
done
```

In this case, you can use an associative array to store the list of authorized users:

```
declare -A authorized_users=()
while read -r username; do
  authorized_users[$username]=1
done <input_file
```

...and then you can check if a user is in that list like so:

```
if [[ ${authorized_users[$possible_username]} ]]; then
  echo "User is authorized!"
fi
```

Note that associative array syntax was added in bash 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to clear it up for you.. there are some logics you may wish to look at since if its any other user it will just return the last skip everything.. anyhow..

there are questions to ask since if you are looping the input, then within the for loop you are exiting so it will end the input unsure of what it is your are trying to achieve, as it stands the only use the for loop has is the first output where a user enters the users as a space seperated list - it is not designed to keep on returning the prompt to the user...

so I have updated the script to loop around and ask for user input if it matches fail list:

(sorry if it is now way off what you wanted - I think it may have been more what you wanted? )

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "debug0"
i=0;

#Maybe you want something to measure bad input
# right now only if user puts in #end 3 times will this pass
# so again look at the logics if needed add the attempts++ to skip everything..
max_attempts=3;

# current running attempts set as 0;
attempts=0;



#start function repeats for user input
function start() { 
     echo "Username: "
     read input
     # run process input function
     process_input
}

# The process input function works out what user has put in
function process_input()  { 
   # Go through for loop of users command
    loggedin=$(users);
   for auth in ${loggedin[@]}; do
       echo "debug.5"
       echo "debug1"
       # if current value from users output matches the user input
       if [[ $auth == $input ]]; then
        echo "debug2"
        echo "authentication success"
        #unsure what you are reading here since your not asking for a prompt
        read;
        exit 0;
        # either if input matches #end or anything after 3 attempts that 
        # does not match admin
        elif [[ $auth == "#end" ]] || [[ $attempts -gt $max_attempts ]]; then

        echo "debug3"
         echo "authentication failed - failed attempts $attempts "
        ((attempts++))

        start;
      fi
done

echo "skip everything"
# removed comment from start function below if you want to get user to re-enter 
start;

}

# begin your program by running the start function
start;
```